# Create named variables in the local scope from JSON keys

Tags: python, json, function

Is there a way I can create named variables in the local scope from a json file?

[document json](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=d29e505b4e5937ecefb7027a0d692f51)

This is my json file, I would like to create variables in the local scope named as the path of my json dictionary

This is how I manually create them, I would like to do it automatically for all the json file. Is it possible?

```
class board(object):
    def __init__(self, json, image):
        self.json = json
        self.image = image  

    def extract_json(self, *args):
        with open(self.json) as data_file:
            data = json.load(data_file)
            jsonpath_expr = parse(".".join(args))
            return jsonpath_expr.find(data)[0].value    

MyAgonism = board('document.json', './tabellone.jpg')

boxes_time_minutes_coord = MyAgonism.extract_json("boxes", "time_minutes", "coord")
boxes_time_seconds_coord = MyAgonism.extract_json("boxes", "time_seconds", "coord")
boxes_score_home_coord = MyAgonism.extract_json("boxes", "score_home", "coord")
```

Comment: Do you mean multiple, single-value variables or one dictionary variable?

Comment: I'm not totally clear what you want, but have you tried simply loading the whole JSON string into Python data structures with [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) or [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads)?

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking, can you be more specific? If you have tried writing some code, it would help if you shared it.

Comment: How are you doing it manually ?

Comment: This sounds a lot like 'kan I haz kode pls', please post what you have tried. For more guidelines please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you post a small exmaple json here instead of a large json on an external site? And can you post some code? I don't know what you mean by "i load manually" and maybe an example would help. One typically loads the json into a single variable, such as `config = json.load(open('somefile.json'))` and then addresses the data such as `config["background"]`.

Comment: @Ilyas I so hope OP's not typing the dictionaries by hand! :D

Comment: Maybe the best way to approach this is for you to review [json.load](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html#json.load) and let us know if it doesn't suite your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're making this much more complicated than it needs to be.

```
with open('document.json') as f:
    d = json.load(f)

time_minutes_coords = d['boxes']['time_minutes']['coord']
time_seconds_coords = d['boxes']['time_seconds']['coord']
score_home_coords = d['boxes']['score_home']['coord']
```

If you actually want to create named variables in the local scope from the keys in your json file, you can use the `locals()` dictionary (but this is a terrible idea, it's far better just to reference them from the json dictionary).

```
# Flatten the dictionary keys.
# This turns ['boxes']['time_minutes']['coord'] 
# into "boxes_time_minutes_coord"
def flatten_dict(d, k_pre=None, delim='_', fd=None):
    if fd is None:
        fd = {}
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        if k_pre is not None:
            k = '{0}{1}{2}'.format(k_pre, delim, k)
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            flatten_dict(v, k, delim, fd)
        else:
            fd[k] = v
    return fd

fd = flatten_dict(d)
locals().update(fd)

print boxes_time_minutes_coord
```

Lots of caveats, like the possibility of overwriting some other variable in your local scope, or the possibility that two dictionary keys could be identical after flattening unless you choose a delimiter that doesn't appear in any of the dictionary keys. Or that this won't work if your keys contain invalid characters for variable names (like spaces for example).

Comment: You are right, but I still have to load them "manually". I would like to create a function that automatically store all the values (coords, foreground, etc.) and assign them to a variable. Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "manually"? In my example, you only have to read and parse the json once.  In your example, you're reading and parsing the json *every* time the function is called.

Comment: I mean you have to "load" the value in these three variables. But my json file is quite long with a tons of value and I don't want to write 100 lines of code to "load" the values in my variables. I would like to create a function that actually load all the values in variables at the same time.

Comment: @Eldar88 Updated the answer, but I think you should really not do what you are trying to do.

Comment: oops, left off `.iteritems()`.  Updated

Comment: Thanks. I've edit my code in this way: [link](http://paste.ofcode.org/yXHHbZbFxcfGycU6rkuYjN) Not sure if I have to move that function as a method of my class though.